# Redefining a structure defined in a base class from a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've made a class(named BST) for Binary Search Tree in C++ and now trying to make a class(named AVL) for AVL trees that inherits the BST class. I've defined a structure(named node) inside my BST class and now would like to add an extra member 'height' to it when using it in the derived AVL class. I can't find a way how to redefine the structure and add an extra member to it only while it is being used for the AVL class.
Here is my code for BST class:

```
class BST
{
protected:
struct node
{
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
node* root;

public:
BST()
{
    this->root = NULL;
}
void insert(int val);
void display();
void displayPretty();
void displaySorted();
int min();
int max();
int height();
void remove(int val);
int after(int val);
int before(int val);
static bool isBST(BST tree);
~BST()
{
    removeAll(this->root);
}

protected:
node* create(int val);
node* insertInto(node* root,int val);
void displayLevelOrder(queue<node*>* q);
void displayPretty(node* p, int indent);
void displayInorder(node* root);
node* getMin(node* root);
node* getMax(node* root);
int heightOf(node* root);
node* removeFrom(node* root,int val);
void removeAll(node* root);
node* getSuccessorOf(int val,node* root,node* prev);
node* getPredecessorOf(int val,node* root,node* next);
static bool isBST(node* root,int min,int max);

};
```

And my incomplete code for AVL class is :

```
class AVL : public BST
{
protected:
struct node
{
    // redefine node here (by adding the 'height' member)
    // such that all the node variables/pointers in BST (e.g. root)
    // also get created with this new definition
};

public:
AVL() : BST(){} 
void insert(int val);
void remove(int val);

private:
node* insertInto(node* root,int val);
node* removeFrom(node* root,int val)

};
```

I've tried using structure inheritance like this:

```
struct avlnode : node
{
    int height;
};
```

But the problem here is `avlnode->left` and `avlnode->right` are being `node*` type instead of `avlnode*` type and thus I can't access the height member from them.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: So basically you want to introduce a field equivalent for the `int heightOf(node* root);` function... I'd say, don't do it, use the function whenever needed, so you never have to worry about outdated heights when changing the tree.

Comment: Instead of redefinition, deriving the `node` in `AVL` should work i.e. `struct Node: BST::Node { }` in class `AVL`. `BST` does not need to know about the "extension" of nodes. You had to be carefully when nodes had to be copied but IMHO this is not necessary in a tree. If you want to access the nodes then you have, of course, to apply an upcast e.g. `(AVL::node*)` or `static_cast<AVL::node*>()`. (`dynamic_cast<>()` will not work without anything virtual.)

Comment: But it takes O(n) time to calculate height. And in an AVL rotation we need to find height of a node in each step, and calling a function each time will not only increase the time but also result in repeated computations.

Comment: You probably have to overload certain methods of `class BST` in `class AVL` for proper handling of nodes. Introducing something like a virtual display method in `struct node` (and similar methods for other node specific things) could simplify things (and could make overloading of `class BST` methods unnecessary).

Comment: May be, it is worth to look at the design of [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) where nodes (keys) and the less operator are provided as template parameters. AFAIK, `std::set<>` uses a binary tree internally.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP, the derived class was named `AVLTree`. Unfortunately, the OP is not an **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. The "exciting" implementation details are left out (or even not yet developed). After recalling how an **[AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)** works, I decided just to ignore it. Thus, I want to show simply how the deriving of classes could work:

*Note: I split the sample code to prevent nested scrolling boxes.*

Source `trees.cc`:

First some headers of the standard library I want to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
```

The declaration of base class `BTree`:

```
class BTree {
```

starting with the embedded class for the nodes:

```
  // types:
  protected:
    struct Node {
      int value;
      Node *pLeft, *pRight;

      // constructor.
      Node(int value): value(value), pLeft(nullptr), pRight(nullptr) { }
      // destructor.
      virtual ~Node() { delete pLeft; delete pRight; }
      // disabled:
      Node(const Node&) = delete;
      Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;

      // prints node.
      virtual void print(std::ostream &out)
      {
        out << "Node " << value;
      }
    };
```

... variables...

```
  // variables:
  protected:
    Node *_pRoot;
```

... and methods.

```
  // methods:
  public:
    // constructor.
    BTree(): _pRoot(nullptr) { }
    // destructor.
    ~BTree() { delete _pRoot; }
    // disabled:
    BTree(const BTree&) = delete;
    BTree& operator=(const BTree&) = delete;

    // inserts a node.
    bool insert(int value) { return insert(_pRoot, value); }
    // prints the tree.
    void print(std::ostream &out, bool inOrder)
    {
      if (_pRoot) {
        if (inOrder) printInfix(out, _pRoot, 0);
        else print(out, _pRoot, 0);
      } else out << "EMPTY." << std::endl;
    }

  // internal methods:
  protected:
    // creates and inserts a node.
    bool insert(Node *&pNode, int value);
    // prints a sub-tree.
    void print(std::ostream &out, Node *pNode, int indent);
    // prints a sub-tree in order.
    void printInfix(std::ostream &out, Node *pNode, int indent);

};
```

The implementation of the internal methods:

```
bool BTree::insert(Node *&pNode, int value)
{
  if (!pNode) {
    pNode = new Node(value);
    return true;
  }
  if (value == pNode->value) return false; // ERROR!
  return insert(
    value < pNode->value ? pNode->pLeft : pNode->pRight, value);
}

void BTree::print(std::ostream &out, Node *pNode, int indent)
{
  out << std::setw(indent) << "";
  pNode->print(out);
  out << std::endl;
  indent += 2;
  if (pNode->pLeft) print(out, pNode->pLeft, indent);
  if (pNode->pRight) print(out, pNode->pRight, indent);
}

void BTree::printInfix(std::ostream &out, Node *pNode, int indent)
{
  if (pNode->pLeft) printInfix(out, pNode->pLeft, indent + 2);
  out << std::setw(indent) << "";
  pNode->print(out);
  out << std::endl;
  if (pNode->pRight) printInfix(out, pNode->pRight, indent + 2);
}
```

The derived class for a 2<sup>nd</sup> tree:

```
class BTree2: public BTree {
```

starting with the embedded class for the derived nodes:

```
  // types:
  protected:
    struct Node: public BTree::Node {
      int height;

      // constructor.
      Node(int value, int height):
        BTree::Node(value), height(height)
      { }
      virtual ~Node() = default;
      // disabled:
      Node(const Node&) = delete;
      Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;

      // prints node.
      virtual void print(std::ostream &out)
      {
        out << "Node " << value << " (height: " << height << ")";
      }
    };
```

... no variables, but some derived methods...

```
  // methods:
  public:
    // constructor.
    BTree2(): BTree() { }
    // destructor.
    ~BTree2() = default;
    // disabled:
    BTree2(const BTree2&) = delete;
    BTree2& operator=(const BTree2&) = delete;

    // inserts a node.
    bool insert(int value)
    {
      return insert((Node*&)_pRoot, value, 0);
    }

  // internal methods:
  protected:
    // creates and inserts a node.
    bool insert(Node *&pNode, int value, int height);
};
```

... and the implementation:

```
bool BTree2::insert(Node *&pNode, int value, int height)
{
  if (!pNode) {
    pNode = new Node(value, height);
    return true;
  }
  if (value == pNode->value) return false; // ERROR!
  return insert(
    (Node*&)(value < pNode->value ? pNode->pLeft : pNode->pRight),
    value, pNode->height + 1);
}
```

Last but not least the main function with a small test:

```
// main function
int main()
{
  // some test data
  int data[] = { 3, 7, 21, 2, 12, 1, 104, 13 };
  enum { nData = sizeof data / sizeof data[0] };
  // binary tree
  { std::cout << "Binary Tree:" << std::endl;
    BTree bTree;
    std::cout << "Build..." << std::endl;
    for (int value : data) bTree.insert(value);
    std::cout << "Print Hierarchy..." << std::endl;
    bTree.print(std::cout, false);
    std::cout << "Print Sorted..." << std::endl;
    bTree.print(std::cout, true);
    std::cout << "Destroy..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  // derived binary tree
  { std::cout << "Derived Binary Tree:" << std::endl;
    BTree2 bTree;
    std::cout << "Build..." << std::endl;
    for (int value : data) bTree.insert(value);
    std::cout << "Print Hierarchy..." << std::endl;
    bTree.print(std::cout, false);
    std::cout << "Print Sorted..." << std::endl;
    bTree.print(std::cout, true);
    std::cout << "Destroy..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

I uploaded the sample on **[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3AEG0P)**.

I compiled and tested it with gcc in cygwin on Windows 10:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o trees trees.cc

$ ./trees.exe 
Binary Tree:
Build...
Print Hierarchy...
Node 3
  Node 2
    Node 1
  Node 7
    Node 21
      Node 12
        Node 13
      Node 104
Print Sorted...
    Node 1
  Node 2
Node 3
  Node 7
      Node 12
        Node 13
    Node 21
      Node 104
Destroy...

Derived Binary Tree:
Build...
Print Hierarchy...
Node 3 (height: 0)
  Node 2 (height: 1)
    Node 1 (height: 2)
  Node 7 (height: 1)
    Node 21 (height: 2)
      Node 12 (height: 3)
        Node 13 (height: 4)
      Node 104 (height: 3)
Print Sorted...
    Node 1 (height: 2)
  Node 2 (height: 1)
Node 3 (height: 0)
  Node 7 (height: 1)
      Node 12 (height: 3)
        Node 13 (height: 4)
    Node 21 (height: 2)
      Node 104 (height: 3)
Destroy...


$
```

Notes:

1. Introducing virtual methods in `struct Node` enables the usage of `dynamic_cast<>()`. AFAIK, `dynamic_cast<>()` may be applied to pointer types only. Thus, I simply did a C-cast (i.e. `(Node*&)`) what C++ purists actually don't like.
2. The `insert()` of `class BTree2` does not use any insertion stuff of `class BTree`. This is necessary to ensure that every node in the tree is actually a `BTree2::Node`.
3. The `BTree::print()` doesn't need to be overloaded due to the virtual `Node::print()` methods.

This design simply shows some ways to re-use the code.

Templates are just a different opportunity. The standard library (e.g. [std::set<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)) provides an example how it could look.

Answer (score 0):

If you use structure inheritance, the Derived class inherits the *struct node* as it is and you get a *node** instead of *avlnode**.

Now, you may want to redefine your struct *node* in the derived class, which will hide the *node* in Parent and prefer *'node'* in Derived class, but any functions you use from the Parent class will use the definition of *'node'* from Parent class.

Maybe you can declare a height variable in *node* of the parent class and use it in derived class only or, declare a `vector<int> heights` in the Derived class and store heights in there.

Also, declare the *struct node* outside the class and use an instance of it as a member of your classes.